# Can I measure if current is on or off in cable with 24v DC (in a cheap way)

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I have a number of valves that control the heating in rooms in our house. The valves have a pin on top which opens or closes the valve. The position of the pin is controlled by a regulator that sits on top of the pin and can be seen in the image below. The valves are either open or closed. I would like to monitor the valve position. I assume the only way to to that is to measure if a regulator is getting any current.

According to what I have found from the net it seems the regulators are getting 24V DC and using 1 W. Would that mean A=W/V => 1/24 => 42mA? On another place it says that "start current is <300 mA during maximum 2 minutes". The whole product name is Roth A5 24V Nc 1W. I assume A5 is the product name and does NC mean "normally closed"?

I don't know how regulators like these work, do they get current all the time they are open or only part of the time, but let's assume the get current all the time they are open.

Question:
What kind of non-intrusive sensor can I use to monitor if the regulator is open or closed?

I would like it to be non-intrusive because I'm not sure what the company that has delivered the system says if I cut the cords and install something. Since I have eight cords to monitor I would prefer if there was something costing like max 10€/sensor.

**Update** I changed the picture to ones from my own system where the regulator is open. I can also confirm that the regulators that are open are very hot on the top.

**Update 2** Added a picture of the cables to the regulators.

**Update 3** The original task was to log when the valve was open or not. Since the valves are either open or closed and not purposely in between I ended up ordering some micro-switches that the regulator will trigger when it opens.

[image: The cables to the regulators]

[image: Regulator in place and open]

[image: The valve and the underside of the regulator]

Comment: are they AC or DC (poke the terminals with a multimeter)

Comment: @Jasen I'm sorry, but I don't have a multimeter, but according to the broschure it says "Outputs amount and voltage 6/12/18 24V DC" (my translation of the text).

Comment: The device type name is regelmotor, which turns to be more likely a motor with gearbox, so any information is useless if you don't have a position feedback sensor.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: I had noted the 'regelmotor' terminology too and wondered if 'motor' in Swedish covers more generic actuators such as solenoids, etc.

Comment: @MathiasR: What is your requirement? Do you want to know valve open / not open / % open? Why do you not trust the controller?

Comment: @transistor I only need to know if it is open or closed. I was planning on logging how much the valve needs to be open per room to keep the set temperature. The system works great but we have build a new house and put a lot of effort on energy efficiency and this would verify that. Also there is a hatch to the attic in one of two "identical" bedrooms and by measuring  this i could see if the hatch needs more insulation.

Comment: I think you're going to need to measure the 'amount' of open and that will require measuring the average voltage or current (they'll be proportional so either will do) to each valve. We need to figure out the control signal for that.

Comment: The regulator is either open (more blue is visible) or closed (no blue is visible). I'll see if I can check the current according to the schematic below.

Comment: As from earlier picture from the seller page I have noticed that the part coming out of the top wasn't at such height as yours on the photo. This could mean that indeed there is a motorized valve inside and you can have a visual check wheather is open or closed when the upper round tap comes out, and you controller could output +/-24Vdc depending if it qants to open/close the valve. At this point you should borrow some multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

from what I've read of these they get current that makes them hot then their inside swells up and pushes on the pin, and also switches them to a lower power mode where they use less current.

it looks they are normally powered from 24V AC

for determining their operation you've got two options, either you fit a split core current transformer around only one of the conductors in the cable,(brown or blue doesn't matter which)  or you connect a voltage sensor (eg: optocupler arranged for 24V AC operation) across to the same terminals that the brown and blue wires go to.

Comment: It seems the valve is "normally open", i.e. the pin is pushed up, but the regulator is "normally closed", i.e. the regulator pushes the pin down.

Comment: So if you attach the device with no electrical connection the heating will be off. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit after Jasen's answer.]

These are like TRV - thermostatic radiator valve - actuator heads but are (as the later added photos show) installed on a manifold for under-floor water heating system. The valve appears to be sprung open. Placing the regulator on it closes the valve. When current is applied to the coil the actuator expands and allows the valve to spring open. This has the advantage that over-expansion of the regulator will 'leave the valve behind' rather than apply excessive force to it.

The most basic 'mechanical' version of these TRV valves use a wax plug inside the head arranged so that on expansion with heat the valve is closed.

Your device has only two wires and this means there can not be any feedback to the controller. If the valve defaults to closed then applying current to the coil will cause expansion and open the valve. Proportional control can be achieved by varying the heating current.

The statement "start current is <300 mA during maximum 2 minutes" may mean that when starting from cold it gives 300 mA for up to 2 minutes to get things moving quickly. It would then reduce current to a maintaining value. That number is important because your power supply would have to provide enough current for all the valves to run full power simultaneously.

If it is a thermal expansion unit I would expect the controller to control the valve by monitoring room temperature and adjusting the current to the coil to get the desired heating. Normally this would be done by pulsing the unit on and off and increasing the power by increasing the on-time. Your '6/12/18 24V DC' comment is confusing in that regard.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fowXub.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simple home-made voltage probe.*

If you don't have a multimeter it's unlikely that you have a bunch of LEDs and resistors lying around but if you do you could make a simple 24 V probe using the circuit of Schematic 1. Touch the red lead to the brown on your regulator and black to the blue. If the green lights up you've got DC supply. If red lights up the supply is reversed. If both light you've got an AC supply. You may also be able to deduce pulsing and reduction in voltage by the LED brightness. If you report back on your findings we can help further.

You could contact [Roth-Nordic](http://roth-nordic.se) and ask for a data sheet and post a link here.

---

Additional details on TRV valves (which I originally thought these were).

There are many available for home heating control including wireless units with temperature feedback. The wireless units are battery operated and use motors with worm-gear drive to move the valve pin. The motor solution means that battery life can be extended because no power is required to maintain position. See [OpenTRV](http://opentrv.org.uk/) for the hacker's version under development. See [HomeMatic](http://www.eq-3.de/produkt-detail-aktoren/items/homematic-funk-heizkoerperthermostat.html) for an example of a commercial unit.

Comment: I actually have a bunch of LEDs and resistors (and a breadboard and jumper cables) lying around but I'm not very good at reading schematics. So I put the resistor on the cable and after I split the cable in two and put the LEDs with the polarity in different ways?

Comment: That would work. The 'flat' on the base of a standard LED is the negative. Question: do the actuator caps move? Do I see more blue ring in your photo than in the brochure photo. If so position sensing is a possibility.

Comment: Even though I don't have a multimeter (yet) I have built this "termometer" for the garage (https://i.imgur.com/0qJoDF1.jpg) which I then redesigned to this (https://i.imgur.com/kZivytd.jpg) which reports through http://ronnlunds.duckdns.org/Temperatur.

Comment: Excellent. Imagine what you could do if you had a multimeter too! I see from your photos that the devices are in the service area of your house and not in the rooms on the radiators. Is it under-floor heating or radiators? And my other question: do the regulator caps move up and down with heat? (Does the blue ring get bigger?)

Comment: It is under-floor heating. When the valve is open blue is shown, otherwise the cap is completely down and no blue is shown. Just checked and three regulators are open at the moment and they all show equal amount of blue so that leads me to the conclusion they cannot be partly open, only open or closed.

Comment: If it's only on/off control then you have many options. The simplest is a microswitch mounted above each actuator.

Comment: I added an image of the cables to the regulators. I'll get a multimeter tomorrow, then we'll see if it's AC or DC. But the microswitch alternative seems compelling. Can you suggest a suiteable one?